# ParameterBindingException when using PowerShellOnTargetMachines task of VS release management

Tags: release-management, tfs-2015, ms-release-management

In my Release definition, I have a task for **Run PowerShell on target machine**. The powershell script is a **DSC Configuration** file with built-in resource. It used to work fine until I added 2 new mandatory string parameters. Now the task poops out and asks for missing parameters. Even though I specified those in **Script Arguments** section in the format as:

```
-ModulesSourcePath "$(ModulesPath)" -ProvidersSourcePath "$(ProvidersPath)"
```

Here, *ModulesPath* and *ProvidersPath* are custom environment variables. Powershell task is also part of this environment.

Here is my configuration file:

```
Configuration DeploymentPreRequisites_Configuration
{
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [String]$ModulesSourcePath,

        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [String]$ProvidersSourcePath
    )

    Node ('localhost')
    {
        File CopyProvider
        {
            DestinationPath = "$env:ProgramFiles\PackageManagement\ProviderAssemblies\nuget"
            Checksum        = "ModifiedDate"
            Ensure          = "Present"
            Recurse         = $true
            SourcePath      = $ProvidersSourcePath
            Type            = "Directory"
            MatchSource     = $true
        }
    }
}

DeploymentPreRequisites_Configuration
```

I also verified that Script Arguments are resolved correctly in the log files.

```
##[debug]scriptPath = C:\temp\somepath\Deploy\EnsureModulesAndResources.ps1
##[debug]scriptArguments = -ModulesSourcePath "<src-path>" -ProvidersSourcePath "<dest-path>"
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Shouldn't your Script Arguments be -ModulesSourcePath $(ModulesPath) ?-ProvidersSourcePath $(ProvidersPath)?

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: Dummy! My problem was not specifying the arguments when invoking configuration. I changed and it fixed the issue and moved to next error. If my source path is local to target node, it works however if I specify a shared network path, it throws errors.    `SourcePath must be specified if you want to configure the destination directory recursively. Make sure that SourcePath is a directory and that it is accessible. CategoryInfo :InvalidArgument: (:) [], CimException FullyQualifiedErrorId :MI RESULT 4
The path cannot point to the root directory or to the root of a net share.`

Comment: @Sam - User credential which you have used to login tfs account, login to remote machine and try to access network source path. Is it accessible ?

Comment: Yes it's accessible!.

Comment: Please consider providing the solution as an answer and marking that as the solution.